# Can I give a button two commands with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, horizontal-scrolling

I created a page split into seven parts and two colomn divs on each page. When I click the right buttton I scroll to the next column and when I click the left I scroll to the left column. The problem is, let's say I am on page one and I scroll from the second to the third column, I am off the page and have to manually move the x scroll-bar.
Is there a way I can just program the buttons to force the x overflow as well?

Thanks

CSS

```
<style>
#contents {
width: 3500px; <!--Total size of the large container-->
height: 200px;
position: absolute; }

#container {
height: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
border: 1px #000 solid;
   }
#container, .col {
width: 500px;<!--total size of each column.-->
}
.col {

float: left;
 }
</style>
```

HTML

```
  <!--Column 1--> 
  <div class="col">
<p>Put your content here...</p>
<button class="left">Left</button>
<button class="right">right</button>
 </div><!--end div column 1-->
```

I did this for 6 more columns.

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
   var colwidth = $('#container').width(),
contwidth = $('#contents').width(),
getOffset = function() {
    return parseInt($('#container').css('margin-left'));
};

 $(".left").click(function(){
if (getOffset() === 0) return false;

$("#contents").animate({left: '+=' + colwidth},500);
$("#container").animate({'margin-left': '-=' + colwidth},500);
});
$(".right").click(function(){
if (getOffset() === contwidth - colwidth) return false;

$("#contents").animate({left: '-=' + colwidth},500);
$("#container").animate({'margin-left': '+=' + colwidth},500);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign multiple functions to a click, you can call a function from your existing function, or create a new function exclusively for calling your other 2 functions.

Comment: You can also separate function calls with `;` in `onclick`, but here it looks like the code would belong in the `$(".left").click(function(){...}` and `$(".right").click(function(){...}`. However, this does not answer the actual question of how to programmatically move the x-scrollbar with the button clicks.